# Erase function in vector doesn't remove pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, recursion, vector

I'm trying to recursively print out data from an array of dynamic pointers stored inside a vector. 
Using the erase function for vectors, I came up with this code:

```
void output(vector<Person*> array)  
{
   unsigned long size=array.size();
   if(size==0){
   }
   else{
      array[0]->displayData();
      array.erase(array.begin());
      output(array);
    }
}
```

While this code works (I'm able to print out all my data), the erase function didn't "delete" the pointer.

So I was really surprised when I called the output function again in my driver program using the same array variable and was able to reprint the data.

How am I able to print the data accordingly if the erase function is not deleting the pointer?
If it's not deleting the pointer because it's dynamic, then what does the "erase" function do with the pointer at the specific location?

Thanks.

Comment: `erase` removes the post from the vector, and calls its destructor. the destructor of a plain pointer does absolutely nothing. consider using smart pointers

Comment: Incidentally, erasing from the front of the vector is terribly inefficient. You should probably refactor your algorithm to either erase from the back or erase everything at the end of the algorithm.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I would just erase all vector at once (and put the display in the destructor if you really want to see how the vector is being destroyed).

Comment: @MatteoItalia Sure I'll look into erasing from the back. Erasing from the front is inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How am I able to print the data accordingly if the erase function is not deleting the pointer?

Since you are always passing the array by value you are always erasing copies of the original array. Moreover, the objects to which those pointers refer are never deleted.

> If it's not deleting the pointer because it's dynamic, then what does the "erase" function do with the pointer at the specific location?

Absolutely nothing. When you remove an element from a container it's just just the element that is destroyed, not what it points to.

How would the vector know that you stored a pointer to stuff allocated with `new`, and that it's not stuff shared with other objects? If you want to specify that the vector actually "owns" those objects, use an appropriate smart pointer, or just store the objects directly (and not pointers to them).

---

Also, as already said in the comment above, removing elements from the front of the vector is terribly inefficient, since each time it has to shift all the other elements back of one place, so emptying the vector becomes an O(N^2) operation when it would be O(1).

Either refactor your algorithm to pop elements from the back, or just clear the whole vector at the end.

Comment: What? If the copy constructor and destructor are properly implemented a double free cannot ever happen. Also, he's passing pointers around, so there's no destructor involved...

Comment: Ahh ok, you're right about the last part, the elements are pointers so you end up with dangling ones not effectively destructing them, will remove my comment. Was thinking somehow about actual objects or `unique_ptr`s, by habit :)

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll look into the appropriate changes. Really appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Your `output` takes the vector by value, so you don't delete anything but just a copy. Maybe I didn't understand your question, can you post more code? And have no idea why you need a recursive function to erase the vector, why not just calling `array.erase(array.begin(), array.end())`? And btw you shouldn't call your parameter `array`, `array` is a class for static-like arrays defined in `<array>`, so it is not a good idea to have name clashes (in case you may be including `<array>` and `using namespace std;`)

Comment: Yes! That makes a lot more sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The main goal of the recursive function is intended to print the data. I used the erase function so instead of iterating through the array, I can just delete the first element and thereby shifting the elements one position to the left. In doing so, I would only need to print the first element.

Comment: Why not putting the display into the destructor of `Person`? This way you will display the data. But anyhow, the main problem is passing by value I'd say. And indeed, as @Matteo Italia said, it is EXTREMELY inefficient to erase the first element. That's because all elements have to shift to the right, and this is expensive, `O(N)` basically. Now you do this for all elements, so you end up with `O(N^2)` complexity for something that should be `O(1)` or at most `O(N)` if the `Person` has a destructor.

Comment: But if I put the display into the destructor, wouldn't I call the display again when the program ends thereby calling the destructor?

Answer (score 0):

a little suggestion

```
void output( vector<Person*>& pvec )  
{
    for( auto p : pvec )
    {
        p->displayData();
        // delete p; // uncomment this if you also want content destroyd
    }
    pvec.clear();
}
```